# Displaying Video in Picture Box of a Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, video, aforge

I want to display the video in pictureBox1 from a source. I've tried many things but still not working. My code is as follows but is showing no output.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace SampleCode
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AVIReader reader = new AVIReader();
            reader.Open("D:\roadtest.avi");           // path of .avi file

            while (reader.Position - reader.Start < reader.Length)
            {
                // get next frame
                Bitmap image = reader.GetNextFrame();
                pictureBox1.Image = image;
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What does not work, do you get an error?

Comment: `@"D:\roadtest.avi"`?

Comment: that code don't compile first of all. `reader.Open("D:\roadtest.avi");` change to `reader.Open("D:\\roadtest.avi");` or `reader.Open(@"D:\roadtest.avi");`

Comment: and now you real problem is the location of your code. form load will not refresh control visually. What you will end up with is the last frame. You need to run that piece of code within a background worker but AFTER the form load event is done. Most likely Form_Loaded()

Comment: The window is not yet visible when the Load event fires.  That doesn't happen until it completes.  So you could only ever see the *last* frame.  If you don't see that either then the code threw an exception, look in the Output window.  This needs to be significantly revised, you have to use a timer to display the frames at the correct frame rate.  Best not to write this yourself, you can embed Windows Media Player in a form.

Comment: It's showing a single frame now. What to do?

Comment: Actually I hunt down what my problem was. I need a mechanism from which I can visualise my video a little slow. WHat the above logic does that it quickly renders the whole video and shows me the last frame.